# Email piping with php script

Tags: php, email, pipe, command-line-interface

Hi' I want to forward all the emails(which are come to my inbox) to php script and retrieve email content and save it in a file. So do that I was add email forwarder with piping path correctly.

Address to Forward :tickets@ana.stage.centuryware.org

Pipe to a Program : /home/centuryw/public_html/stage/ana/osticket/upload/api/pipe.php

I have used following script as pipe.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php –q
<?
/* Read the message from STDIN */
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
/* Saves the data into a file */
$fdw = fopen("mail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
/* Script End */
```

But there was no output file and all email are bounced to my inbox again. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I never thought pipe'ing. Thanks for progress you created in my mind :)

Comment: I just trying forward emails to simple php script and write the email contents in to the file. I can add mail forwarder easily using Cpanel. This is not a dumb idea.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the PHP file has the execute bit set (i.e. `chmod +x pipe.php`).

Comment: yeah. I set file permission as 755....:(. There was no errors with script. But also there was no output file (mail.txt)

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that file?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is 2 years old but hopefully this will help anybody who stumbles across it as I did.

I had exactly the same issue and I spent ages trying to log errors etc. I then noticed that my script (and this one) had PHP short tags (i.e. `<?`) and my PHP config file had these turned off. I changed the tag to `<?php` and the script worked! Obvious but easy to miss...

Comment: @meda this is a setting on PHP's settings file. It has nothing to do with OS.

Answer (score 3):

try the following 2 options to check:

- First, your php file must need to have execute permission(from owner group at least), otherwise it won't work.
- What did you used when you were using forwarder? You need to mention php compiler path at the beginnig also.

I have recently written an article regarding the full detail process of [piping email content to php program](http://codesamplez.com/programming/email-to-php-script) , you will may like to have a look. Let me know if you have any more question. Thanks.

Comment: how do I view the content once I have put in the code in email handler file?

Answer (score 0):

Chanaka -

This doesn't address why there is no output file, but...

Don't you want to use `a+` in your `fopen()` call? The `w+` argument will delete any content that already exists in your output file.

PS: Have you tried doing a simple test which writes to the output file using dummy text (not the input from an e-mail) as the contents?

Jeff Cohan

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. However I solved it by specifying the output file with full path name. Instead of just 'mail.text', i entered '/home/username/public_html/mail.txt'.

Answer (score -1):

If this is actually an email box, why not use [IMAP (PHP)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)? There are lots of classes to read the mail with imap [@ phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=imap&x=0&y=0&go_search=1)

Comment: This is my webmail address and I want forward all the emails to pipe.php script which are coming to my webmail address. I was add email forwarder using Cpanel.

Comment: A webmail address is an e-mail address. Then create a script that reads the emails in to a database. Set a cronjob on that script.

Comment: Polling mail is far less efficient than routing it to the script